# Java Compiler error with multiple generics type

Tags: java, generics, compiler-construction

I have a interface like this:

```
public interface GenericWSEndpoint<T1,T2> {

    public void call(String url,String operationName, T1 requestObject, T2 responseObject,long timeout) throws Exception;

}
```

When I try to define an object with this, it gives

> org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Compilation failure : 
>   incompatible types

Object definition:

```
private static GenericWSEndpoint<BulkCheckBlockageRequest,BulkCheckBlockageResponse> endpoint=GenericWsEndpointFactory.createSpecificEndpoint(WSTypes.CXF);
```

And factory code:

```
public class GenericWsEndpointFactory{

    public static <T1,T2> GenericWSEndpoint createSpecificEndpoint(WSTypes type){
        switch (type) {
        case CXF:

            return new CXFWsEndPoint<T1,T2>();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

and the CXFWsEndPoint(no constructors defined specificly):

```
public class CXFWsEndPoint<T1,T2> implements GenericWSEndpoint<T1, T2>{
.
.
}
```

I have checked the answers about this problem but they are related with definitions like recursive generics

Any ideas?

EDIT: Exception:

> [INFO] Compilation failure
>   ResponseManager\src\main\java\com\x\resman\util\WebServiceUtil.java:[57,142]
>   incompatible types; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T1,T2 exist so
>   that com.x.rbm.ws.service.GenericWSEndpoint conforms to
>   com.x.rbm.ws.service.GenericWSEndpoint
>   found   : com.x.rbm.ws.service.GenericWSEndpoint required:
>
> com.x.rbm.ws.service.GenericWSEndpointequest,com.x.resman.model.checkblockage.BulkCheckBlockageResponse>

Comment: Is there any more information on the exception?

Comment: This interface is fine. Error must be some where else

Comment: Check your right-hand side type, of what type is `GenericWsEndpointFactory.createSpecificEndpoint(WSTypes.CXF);` ?

Comment: Show us the `CXFWsEndPoint` declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the following code:

```
  public static <T1, T2> GenericWSEndpoint<T1, T2> createSpecificEndpoint() {
```

instead of

```
  public static <T1, T2> GenericWSEndpoint createSpecificEndpoint() {
```

Comment: Which IDE are you using (if any) ?

Comment: You should get a warning on that line for this kind of problem (maybe it is an optional one).

Comment: yes but it should not be a warning if it is gonna give a compiler error.

Comment: Maybe Eclipse is badly configured and should show it as an error (can be configured). Let me know if you figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying the Java source version in your Maven POM file? Currently, by default Maven uses 1.5. You probably need something more recent. What version are you using in our IDE?

The relevant Maven configuration is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have 1.6 version in maven and it is compatible with generics. It is not a maven problem also